# Just a basic question for understanding the definition of topological spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

slowly I am moving into the $\mathbb{R}^n$ with my analysis studies.

And with starting so, the author introduced some basic topology terms, for better understanding.

After writing down the three criteriums for inducing a topology onto a set, he also gave the two trivial topologies on any set $X$:

$\mathcal{T}_0:=\lbrace \emptyset,X\rbrace$ and $\mathcal{T}_1:=\mathcal{P}(X)$

And telling: any set element of a topology is regarded **open** in terms of the topology.

So here are my two questions:

Firstly: Is the term **open** in regards to a topology not instantly compareable to the classification of open sets, but rather a term given to any element of a topology, but the whole definition helps to define open sets?

An example which went through my head when trying wrapping my head around topologic spaces:

The empty set, $\mathbb{R}$ and all compact intervalls on $\mathbb{R}$ build a topology, (I hope this even works ;D) than any element in the topology is called **open** regarding the topology, but actually are all closed sets.

---

Second question:

Is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ even possibly a topologic space? it contains compact intervalls and open intervalls?

Maybe a good answer to the first question will also clear my second question :)

I hope someone has the time to help me out

Comment: The empty set, $\mathbb R$, and all compact intervals in $\mathbb R$ do not constitute a topology, because a topology has to be closed under arbitrary unions; for example, $\cup _{n=1}^\infty [1/n,1-1/n]=(0,1)$ would have to be in it

Comment: You need to a little more precise with your questions. The term open with a topology is consistent with all other definitions you have heard. The connection will become clear after a while. For the second, the answer is that it would result in the same as the second topology above (if considered as a base).

Comment: Do keep in mind that the definition of a topology took a long time to evolve, so while easy to state, it represents many person decades of distillation and an appreciation of the definition takes some time.

Comment: For the discrete topology (power set) on $\mathbb R$, all subsets of $\mathbb R$ are open, including closed intervals

Comment: Okey thank you :) yes I was absolute sure I woldnt be able to grasp all its beauty at my state, but I always try to atleast get my personal questions out of the way, before I simply follow the definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^n$ are specific examples of topological spaces. They are quite familiar to us, and we already know what it means for a set to be open or closed.

The purpose of defining a topology abstractly like this is to generalize these familiar spaces. By itself, the axioms of a topology are quite minimal, as the same set can have vastly different topologies.

Let's just take $\Bbb R$ as an example of an underlying set.

- We can define the **trivial topology** which contains only $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$. In this topology, there are only two open sets. Sets like $(0,1)$ are no longer open, even though we might expect them to be.
- On the other end, we can construct the **discrete topology**, in which every subset of $\Bbb R$ is open. Now sets like $[0,1]$ are open. The complement $\Bbb R\setminus[0,1]$ is also open, so actually $[0,1]$ is also closed. In this topology, every possible set is both open and closed.
- The familiar topology on $\Bbb R$ is referred to as just "the usual topology," "the Euclidean topology," or "the metric topology." We begin by first constructing a metric. In this case, it's just the absolute value function. Then we construct a topology where a set $U$ is open if and only if, for every $x\in U$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq U$. It then requires a bit of work to show that this defines a topology. A more common construction is the lazier approach: we declare that any open intervals $(a,b)$ are open, and then include whatever other open sets we need to in order to satisfy the axioms.
- More generally, the metric function on $\Bbb R^n$ gives the distance between $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\ldots, y_n)$ as $|\!|x-y|\!|=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+\cdots+(x_n-y_n)^2}$. We construct the metric topology by declaring that open balls $B_\varepsilon(x)=\{y\in\Bbb R^n:|\!|y-x|\!|<\varepsilon\}$ are open, and then letting this generate a topology as before.

At the end of the day, we almost always use the usual topology on $\Bbb R^n$, but the point is that every time you have heard a set described as "open" before now, this really meant "open in the usual topology."

Comment: This just opend my eyes alot, thank you so much :) This is an excellent add on to the short introduction in my analysis book!